# Spring - keep values of different types in database

Tags: java, database, spring, properties, configuration

Is it possible to keep parameterized values in database and use them as properties in some more advanced way? I want to include type of value, along with key-value pairs. Is there a Spring mechanism that can provide me with that functionality?

Comment: This is called EAV and it's generally a bad idea. What are you trying to actually do?

Comment: I think my problem is not that complicated as EAV. All I need is bunch of constants of various types stored in one table. Those could be part of my business logic as variables but are changeable in runtime. For example, I need few strings, few integers and date... I'm searching for idea how to store them for easiest access from my code?

Comment: @shx You can store all of them as `String` and then manage those that are not `String` in an appropiate way